# Generating different CAN errors with CANoe

Tags: can-bus, capl, canoe

Is it possible to generate CAN protocol errors with CANoe?

Tried searching for it but the word "CAN" is not really search friendly.

Comment: Do you mean CANStress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean disturbing CAN frames, generate error frames then consider trying Vector interface VH6501 - https://vector.com/vi_vh6501_en.html
It's successor of deprecated product named CANstress. Integrates seamlessly with CANoe/CAPL.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can create error frame in CANoe. use IG block and select special frame option in IG configuration. then press send now button to transmit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CAN protocol errors can be generated with CANoe. A detailed example can be found here under Online Vector Help in CANoe (by clicking the help symbol in the CANoe tool): CAPL Functions » CAN » on errorFrame